# Wrong spring application context loaded on test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing

I have my Spring app where the application context is loaded properly and working. But when I try to load it in my tests, the application context loaded does not contain any of the beans declared in config files.

```
@Test
public void testInsertMapitPoint() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {     "classpath:*/application-ds-context.xml","classpath:*/application-dao-context.xml" });
    System.out.println("Bean Names:");
    for (String beanName : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}
```

The displayed test does not show any bean in the context. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a pattern like

```
classpath:*/application-ds-context.xml
       // ^ this guy
```

Spring will load any file that matches that pattern. *Any* meaning it might not find/load any. In this example, it will look for any file called `application-ds-context.xml` that is in any 1st level package.

For example, it will find

```
/classpath-root
    /first
        application-ds-context.xml
```

but it won't find

```
/classpath-root
    application-ds-context.xml
```

or

```
/classpath-root
    /first
        /second
            application-ds-context.xml
```

If that's the behavior you are seeing, your classpath does not contain such a file. Review how you are building your test application.

Comment: Aha. I think he means `classpath*:/application-ds-context.xml`.

Comment: @chrylis Take a look at `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`. The use of `*` in what you are proposing and what OP has are essentially the same, in this case.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry, no. Not exactly. What I was trying to say is that they are both wildcards. But yes, `classpath*:/application-ds-context.xml`  would look for it at the root, rather than one package level down.

Comment: @chrylis It would however not complain if it didn't find anything.

Comment: Completely understood, but I was suspecting that that transposition was *why* it wasn't finding any beans.